# Installing VS Code and Node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to Node.js and I am using VS Code to write a simple program.  The first problem I ran into was that the program would not block on Readline.question.  My searches found no explanation for why this was happening.  I uninstalled and reinstalled both VS Code and Node.js.  The program I am writing still has the same problem and now, vs code will not run in debug mode.  Can anyone point me to a site or documents that might shed some light on these issues?  I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Its easier to assist you in the problem when you provide a code snippet.

Comment: I actually posted some code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74903152/running-node-js-readline-functions?noredirect=1#comment132186192_74903152;  one person answered and said it runs fine on his computer.  So I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both VS Code and Node.js.  I opened the file and the code has the same problem and now, I cannot even debug the code.  Everybody else on earth has no problem with VS Code and Node.js.  So something must be wrong on my computer somewhere.  This is why I am asking for advice...I have to be doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out.